# DLL functionality stops working in UWP app after being packaged into an appx package

Tags: unity-game-engine, dll, hololens, appx

I'm currently having a problem where the functionality of a dll fails to work in my UWP app after packing it into an appx package and sharing it, but it works in a deployment.

Details:

The project itself is built in Unity and is meant to be used on a HoloLens 2. I'm building the Unity project with ARM architecture and it builds as a Visual Studio Solution, and I currently use Visual Studio 2019.

This is where the problem gets confusing. I can deploy the application directly to the HoloLens 2 through VS and the project works with 100% functionality and the dll has no issues. But whenever I create an appx package for the project and send it to the other user, the app will work fine only up until the dll functionality is supposed to happen. And it doesn't cause any error or crash, it just doesn't do anything.

I know dll issues can be a mystery, but I was hoping someone else may have encountered this or can see where I'm going wrong. I made sure to resign the dll's certificate with the same one used for the Unity project and check if any dependencies could be missing, but they all seem to be inherent Windows libraries (which we've installed the respective Microsoft Visual c++ redistributable to make sure that wasn't the problem).

To add some more details that may raise alarms: I compress the folder that the appx package is in to share it, the other user is using a different HoloLens 2, and I share the zip through OneDrive.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried installing via the appx package on your own device? Does it work as expected? You can find the log file of the project at **Device Portal->System->File explorer->LocalAppData->[ProjectName]->TempState**, is there any error message returned? And if you are using some custom DLLs, please make sure their supported UWP version contains the version of your device.

Comment: Is there anything in the player log referencing the DLL? You can access that via the Device Portal's file explorer, under LocalAppData\Packages\<productname>\TempState\UnityPlayer.log

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but yes it does work on my own HoloLens. I went to check the log at the given location and everything seems to be alright on my own end.

Comment: Sounds like other HoloLens device is missing a dependency still.  Possibly making sure other device is same OS version and has needed components enabled too.  Example, does API use something to at needs device to be set into developer mode (example, research mode API)

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue! Turns out it was not a dll specific problem. The other device did not have access to read a required file which we found out by looking at the logs on his device. We were able to change the functionality of reading this file and now it works. Thanks for all the help!